# Kotlin deprecated companion instance

Tags: kotlin

When creating a `private companion object` in Kotlin, why is the  `Companion` static variable marked as `@Deprecated public` in the bytecode? Is that just a workaround to "simulate" a `private` behaviour discouraging developers from using that field (since a public companion object doesn't get marked as deprecated)?

Example:

### Kotlin

```
class MyClassWithCompanion {
    private companion object {
        private val FOO = "FOO"
    }
}
```

### Bytecode

```
// DEPRECATED
// access flags 0x20019
public final static LMyClassWithCompanion$Companion; Companion
@Ljava/lang/Deprecated;()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Deprecated` annotation is placed as an intermediate solution to avoid breaking binary compatibility when a compiler bug was fixed. The field wasn't supposed to be generated as public when the companion object is private, but due to an oversight it was. In Kotlin 1.4, it will be marked as private.

See [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11567) for more information.